# Перенос query между роутами во vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Можно ли как то между роутами переносить строку запроса т.е. все что идет в url после ?. 
Пример, допустим есть роут /route1?q=true при первом входе в приложение если q есть я сохраняю в store. И вот хотелось бы что бы при любом изменении роута у меня q оставалось (есть роуты с другими параметрами уже заданными).
Сейчас реализовал так, в App.vue прописал это

```
created() {
    this.$router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    this.SET_LOADED(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            const routeTo = {
                name: to.name,
                params: to.params,
                meta: to.meta,
                query: {
                    ...to.query,
                    debug: this.debug ? true : null,
                },
            }
            next(routeTo)
        }, 500);
    });
},
```

но как и ожидалось оно не работает, происходит бесконечный редирект (правда не понимаю почему). Можно ли как то реализовать такое в одном каком то месте для всего проекта, а не допиливать к каждой ссылке параметр дополнительный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, чтобы прямо `query` переносить - у меня не получилось. Но, если работать с адресной строкой - то все можно

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const search = location.search
  if (search){
    router.app.$nextTick(()=>{
      history.replaceState(null, '', to.path + search)
    })
  }
  next()
})
```